# Changes doesn't reflect on run time (code and design)

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

Im developing a system using vb2022 its almost done but today the changes I made doesn't reflect on run time.
For example I added a button but when I run the program the button will not show.
Same as the code,  i can write code but it doesnt reflect on run time
Plus im trying to change the startup form into form 2 (initial is form 1) but it doesn't reflect.
What should I do? I didn't change anything I just opened the file and write code. But suddenly this happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your build is failing and VS is automatically running the old output. When that happens, VS will prompt you whether to run the old output or not by default, but many people tell VS not to prompt them again without actually reading the dialogue. Use the Build menu to build your project/solution and pay attention to the Output and Error List windows to see whether it failed or not.

It may be that the compilation is succeeding but VS simply can't overwrite the output files because they are locked, which does happen sometimes. In that case, just delete the entire obj and bin folders from your project folder. You may need to close VS to do so. The next time you build, new output will be created and run.

If this happens regularly then you should probably repair VS and, if it continues after that, reinstall.

Comment: I tried to delete the folder but an error occurred its says

Comment: Cannot delete folder because the folder is open or in use.

Comment: I closed the vb already and everything that is open but im still getting the same error

Comment: @Yyy, then restart your computer.